# How should a video-streaming application play the next video on all its clients at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, video

I am building a .NET Web application whose main functionality is streaming video to end users in the same manner as a TV channel is streaming its content to watchers.

That means that all the users that are using the application at a certain point will have to **watch the same video at the same time**. And when the current video ends, **the next video should play automatically (for all the users)**.

So let’s consider the following scenario:

- 1000 users are watching a video at some point
- The video ends and the next video should be played on every client device
- The back end should decide what is the next video that should be streamed and deliver it (using some mechanism) to the end users
- The next video should now be streamed to all the users.

Application stack: **ASP.NET MVC** for backend, **Javascript/JQuery HTML 5** for frontend.

**Question:**

What is the best way for the server to tell all its clients at the same time which is the next video and how it should be played?

There are currently 2 options on the table:

1. Each client handles an event of “video end” when the current video ends and **sends an Ajax request to the server** asking for information about the next video.
2. The server **keeps a socket connection open** with each of its clients and notifies them all at the same time when the current video ends and the next one should be played.

I am trying to find the best solution for this kind of functionality. Any information is useful.

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at http://signalr.net/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a single right answer for this - either of the approaches you suggested would work. Which is better will likely depend on trading off the pros and cons of each approach for you - for example the Ajax approach will create a 'storm' of requests at the end of every video, and the socket approach requires keeping a large number of sockets open for only occasional traffic.

It is worth saying that having the videos exactly synched across multiple devices is a much tougher problem, in case this is important (it usually is not important - online TV channels will not be exactly synched across devices, for example).

Its also worth saying that it sounds like you are actually producing an online 'linear' TV Channel. In other words, one that a device can just connect to and always get the latest video or live feed on. There are service which will allow you create an online TV Channel like this from a set of videos, which may be worth exploring also.

Comment: Please name such a service that you mentioned at the end of your answer.. thanks

Comment: Some examples: https://viloud.tv, https://www.tvgen.net, http://www.strimm.com, https://www.streamingvideoprovider.com/how_to_create_tv_channel.html. Search for 'Create online TV Channel'. Note, I have not looked in depth or used these so check carefully yourself first.